# Isolating reactive expression

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny

I want to call a particular reactive expression for some`observeEvent` and isolate it for other `observeEvent`. Below I have minimal code for what I want to achieve( my actual app contains many `observeEvent`calling the reactive expression).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  numericInput("Num1", "First number:", 0),

  numericInput("Num2", "Second number:", 0),

  textOutput("Answer"),

  actionButton("Button_1", "Call reactive"),

  actionButton("Button_2", "Don't Call reactive")

)

server <- function(input, output){

  Ans <- reactive({
    a <-input$Num1 + input$Num2
    a
  })

  observeEvent(input$Button_1, {

    output$Answer <- renderText({Ans()})

  })

  observeEvent(input$Button_2, {

    output$Answer <- renderText({isolate(Ans())})

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the above app I have two `actionButtons` `Button_1`(Call reactive) and `Button_2`(Don't Call reactive). As the label suggest for the first button (`Button_1`) I want the reactive expression to be called every time the button is clicked but for the second button (`Button_2`)I want the reactive expression not to be called (even when the inputs change). To prevent the `Button_2` form calling the reactive expression I added `isolate` but that does not prevent the reactive expression from being called.

Is there any way in which a reactive expression can be isolated even when the inputs change?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you expect to happen when `Button_2` is clicked. If you just don't need to see new value, why don't you just comment out the line of code?

Comment: @amatsuo_net in my actual app I am using two `observeEvent`, the first one is to draw a plot and the second one zooms the existing plot. So for the zoom button I do not want the reactive expression to be calculated again. Here I just wanted to make the example as minimal as possible.  Maybe I should edit my code so that it is evident why do I need two `observeEvent`, one which recalculates the reactive expression and one which does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `?eventReactive()`.

So replace the `reactive()` function with

```
  Ans <- eventReactive(input$Button_1,{
    input$Num1 + input$Num2
  })
```

(Then you can also remove the `isolate()` function).

As you mentioned that you have several `observeEvent()` and potentially more conditions, it is worth mentioning that the also works for multiple conditions:

```
  Ans <- eventReactive({input$Button_1;input$Button_2;...},{
    input$Num1 + input$Num2
  })
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Had read about this but never used it in any app so far( did not realise its potential I guess).  It solves more than just this problem that I was facing in my app. Thank you so much!